# AWS S3 SDK for PHP 2 - Get HTTP Request/Response Strings

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a generic HTTP file access API which I use for the system I'm working on. To make it as flexible as possible, it returns request and response data in the form of HTTP strings.

I'm currently implementing a version which interacts with the S3, via the [AWS SDK for PHP 2](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/).

Is there an easy way to quickly get the Request and Response HTTP requests which the S3Client makes when performing operations? If not, is there a more piecemeal way which I can use to not have to fake it?

Basically, I'd like the full-text of both the Request and Response on demand, or at least access to relevant data (headers, response codes, URLs, etc) so I can properly populate the return data for my framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get either the request or response object from a command object. Assuming `$s3` holds an instance of `Aws\S3\S3Client`, you could do something like this:

```
$command = $s3->getCommand('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => '<bucket-name>'));
$request = $command->getRequest();
$response = $command->getResponse();
```

Those objects have methods for viewing the body, headers, status codes, etc. and you can cast them to string to see the string form.

If you want to quickly see the request and response as you are executing commands, you can attach the wire logger, and see what comes out on STDOUT (or STDERR)

```
$s3->addSubscriber(\Guzzle\Plugin\Log\LogPlugin::getDebugPlugin());
$s3->listObjects(array('Bucket' => '<bucket-name>'));
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm trying to this but with the Aws\AutoScaling\AutoScalingClient. I succeed to do `$command = $autoScalingClient->getCommand('createLaunchConfiguration', $newConfig);` but I get an error when calling `$command->getResponse();`, the error  is `Call to undefined method Aws\Command::getResponse()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it using the normal `$response = $autoScalingClient->createLaunchConfiguration($newConfig);` and then `$response->get('@metadata')`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look into the `Guzzle\Http\Client` class, which is an ancestor class to `S3Client`, to have a look at the methods that it makes available.  You can always override some of these methods in your own child of `S3Client` to make accessing this information easier for you.

Ultimately the data you are looking for resides in an object of class `Guzzle\Http\Message\Response`, which I believe is returned `from Guzzle\Http\Client::send()`.

So perhaps in your own implementation of `S3Client` you can override the `send()` method to send the HTTP requests, then process the response data as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's looking pretty close to what I want. I'll give it a shot and then come back here to mark this as the answer if it seems to work. =)